# saving numpy array to file with a certain precision

Tags: python, numpy

I have a following numpy array:

```
geom= [[ 6.          0.2        -1.6        -1.3915    ]
         [ 6.          1.40507435 -1.6        -0.69575   ]
         [ 6.          1.40507435 -1.6         0.69575   ]
         [ 6.          0.2        -1.6         1.3915    ]
         [ 6.         -1.00507435 -1.6         0.69575   ]
         [ 6.         -1.00507435 -1.6        -0.69575   ]]
```

When I save it to the file :

```
np.savetxt(g, geom, fmt ='%f6', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ')
```

My first column gets a format '6.0000008'. Subsequently I want to modify that file to obtain 6.0 or 6. Is there any easy solution to do it?
I have tried to convert string to int, but I am getting the error message in return:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.0000008'
```

Comment: You might try using ``pandas`` instead of numpy. It lets you easily combine data of different types into a single dataframe, which can then be exported to file in a much cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would like to keep the other floats as is you aren't going to find a simple solution to this in NumPy. Granted you could probably use [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) to achieve what you want but it will be significantly more work than just using Pandas (as mentioned by @jakevdp).

You could just import your NumPy array into a Pandas DataFrame, make the changes you want and then output the data into any Pandas acceptable format.

For example, to write a csv:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(geom)
df[0] = df[0].astype(int)
df.to_csv(g, index=False)
```